# Without any SELECT(!): "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection"

Tags: c#, mysql

I know that there are tantamount of question re "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection" (edited: originally wrote "Command") - but in all cases there is some SELECT command involved.

My case is different: on this machine, ***no SELECT commands are executed*** (they are on a different physical computer), only INSERT and UPDATE commands.

How can that happen? Does a `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` or a `command.Prepare()` open a DataReader nonetheless? That would be a WTF, but at least an explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, we still have to see the code you're trying to execute in order to help you. Have you managed to narrow down the problem to something simple? It could be as simple as an assumption that no SELECT or similar is executed and there is one buried deep down into a call hierarchy, this is why creating a [mcve] is so important, it ensures you really have a problem and that we have a small piece of code that reproduces it.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The class contains methods with SELECT clauses. I verified that they are called from a UI application on a different machine only. I added extra logging to those methods and see that they are not called on the machine in question.

Comment: The error message you're quoting implies that you're getting a `MySqlException` (or some other `DbException` type). Please post the full exception stack trace, as per http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: The actual error message Connector/NET uses is “There is already an open DataReader associated _with this Connection_ which must be closed first” (not “with this Command”). I strongly suspect you’re sharing the same `MySqlConnection` across multiple threads. This is not permitted by the `MySqlConnection` API and could easily cause this problem. Rewrite your code to use one `MySqlConnection` per thread and not share them.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger "sharing the same MySqlConnection across multiple threads" That could be the cause. Meanwhile I added a `SemaphoreSlim.Wait` to the public methods of that class, and test again.

Answer (score 2):

Having reviewed the reference source for [`SqlCommand`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,56d1ae9fa62ab68a) and [`OleDbCommand`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/OleDb/OleDbCommand.cs,14ce8b0e2fd212ff), both of those have some fast paths in their `ExecuteNonQuery` method implementations that will try to avoid opening a data reader but both have a slow path which will fall back to using a data reader (apparently, the data reader path has to cope with all possible options and they don't want to repeat all of that code, not unreasonably).

I would suspect that whichever option<sup>1</sup> you're using to connect to [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) will have a *similar* implementation. So, first and foremost, it doesn't have to be `SELECT`s causing the conflict.

The fix *should* be simple though and is good general advice. Don't *share* any database objects. Sure, have one source for your connection string but, in general, if you need a connection object, `new` it up there and then and use it in a `using` statement. Same for command objects. For readers, you won't `new` them up yourself but you still want the `using`.

If you don't *reuse* your database objects, you should never get this error. The only exception (in my book) is if you're using client controlled transactions (e.g. `TransactionScope` or similar) where you do want to share connection objects. But you still don't need to share the command objects. And if the transaction is so broad that you're losing track of all of the commands that (may have) executed on it, I'd suggest it's too big.

---

<sup>1</sup>Last time I looked there were a couple of competing [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) specific implementations of the `IDbConnection` et al hierarchy, plus `OleDbCommand` and family can be used.

Comment: The Command object depends on its Connection, so a Command.Prepare would be excluded (or at least useless).

Comment: Yes, you don't get to *reuse* prepared statements. But the benefits of using connection pooling and not dealing with any threading issues will usually produce a system that performs better overall. If you do have a use case where the benefit of reusing a prepared statement is 100% necessary then you would probably want to do some manual pooling of paired connection/command objects - ask the pool for an command object that's already set up with the correct text and parameters and which will have a dedicated connection, set the parameters, execute, then return to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bradley Grainger's comment (threadsafety issues of MySqlConnection), I could get rid of the problem by making sure that no queries are run in parallel.

This means that the original exception message is likely wrong (some strange paths as mentioned in Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer cannot be excluded).